# ListView applies wrap_content to its items on android

Tags: android, listview

I have `ListView` which I'd like to show custom items with fixed height.Items layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_btn_facebook" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/gameMenuItem"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice fixed height of the root `LinearLayout`.
Adapter class:

```
public class SelectorMenuLoggedOutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static final int ACTION_LOGIN_FACEBOOK=0;
    public static final int ACTION_LOGIN_GOOGLE=1;
    public static final int ACTION_FEEDBACK=2;
    public static final int ACTION_RATE_US=3;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    public SelectorMenuLoggedOutAdapter(Context ctx) {
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        context=ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View res=convertView;
        if (res==null) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    res = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_menu_item_login,null);
                    ((TextView)res.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(context.getText(R.string.selector_menu_login_facebook));
                    ((ImageView)res.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.login_btn_facebook);
                    res.findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    res = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_menu_item_login,null);
                    ((TextView)res.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(context.getText(R.string.selector_menu_login_google));
                    ((ImageView)res.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(R.drawable.login_btn_google);
                    res.findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

However when I set this adapter to my list view it shows rows as like their layout_height=wrap_content:

[image: some description]
Some useless details to tell parser its not mostly the code and there is nothing to add arghhh.

Comment: How do you want actually could you show it here! So that it would be clear for us to know more about your problem. Your question is a little bit unclear.

Comment: I'd like height of list items to be as it stated in the layout not wrap_content

Comment: If i'm not wrong then can you please try doing this. Remove the height as wrap_content and make it match_parent in you view i.e., views which has to be shown inside your list view. Do not make any changes in the LinearLayout just the view in xml code. Do it and tell if it works fine

Comment: There is no wrap_content in my layout(if you check it you'll see its height is 200dp).I want my items to be 40dp height but looks like no matter what height I set to my items(fixed size/match_parent/wrap_content) listview just ignores it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `getView` method you should inflate your views passing the parent `ViewGroup` as the root and `false` for the `attachToRoot` argument.

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_menu_item_login, parent, false)
```

That will allow to the parent of your item hierarchy to get a set of LayoutParams values to layout itself as expected.